# Running 32 bit SQL Server 2005 on 64 bit Windows Server?

Tags: sql-server, 64-bit

If I have a 32 bit version of SQL Server 2005 running on a 64 bit Windows Server does the max amount of memory avail. the SQL Server process increase from 2gb to 4gb. 
 In reading [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2008/11/17/3155406.aspx) blog entry by Mark Russinovich in which he states that

> "All Microsoft server products and data intensive executables in Windows are marked with the large address space awareness flag"

and

> "Because the address space on 64-bit Windows is much larger than 4GB, something I’ll describe shortly, Windows can give 32-bit processes the maximum 4GB that they can address and use the rest for the operating system’s virtual memory."

which leads me to believe that the answer is "yes" but I not totally confident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you will be able to access 4gb of ram per instance however a 64 bit version of sql server, limited to 4gb of ram would outperform the 32 bit version in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is yes - your 32bit sql server should be able to use close to 4gb of ram per instance.

don't use the /3gb switch.

you can see the evidence from his testlimit.exe examples in the blog post that you linked to.